# Is there any way to Merge multiple relationship with Single ID in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image: Node with single ID]

Here you can see all nodes connected with a single ID but when try to apply Cypher query to
merge all data and export as table form it is not working.

I have used a match query but the data is not showing correctly.

One single Id is repeated again and again,

[image: Cyper query]

My expected output will be

[image: Expected outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
match(p:pmid)
optional match(p)-[:By_Auther]->(a:auther)
optional match(p)-[:Having]->(c:citation)
return distinct p.name, a.name, c.Name
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (a:id)-[By_copyright]->(b:copyright), (a)-[has_pub_type]->(c:pub), (a)-[Having_citation]->(d:citation), (a)-[By_author]->(e:author), (a)-[Drom_country]->(f:country)
RETURN a.Name as PMID, d.Name as Citation, e.Name as Author, b.Name as Copy_right,c.Name as Publisher, f.Name as Country
order by d.Name DESC
LIMIT 5
```